# java program how add a function that goes back code if player has inputted it wrong

Tags: java, math, text-based

I have a problem with my program is not with the code is how I am going to do it that's the confusing part that I am stuck with. just to let you know I am a basic java coder I do not understand complicated stuff so bear in mind that my code isn't the best.

-----------------------------------------------------------         program explaintion-----------------------------------------------------------------
let's get into the point of explaining how it works before I show you my problem, ok when you execute the program it prompts you a sort of like a menu in a video game but it's a text-based, it shows you different options like enter player details, play the math game show score and then quit. enter player details it tells player 1 to enter he/she name and then tells another one to input he/she player name then prompts you back to the menu. play the math game is where a player 1 is asked to input he/she math equation after that player 2 has to solve it if he gets it right he gets 10 points if no the player gets no points at all. then repeats for another player to input he/she math equation then prompts you back to the menu. show scores it shows who got the most scores in the math game it calculates who's got the most if both of them got the same score then means a tie then prompts you back to the menu. and the last thing the quit option when you choose that option it stops the program. if the player chooses a wrong choice he gets an error message and puts you back to the menu

ok here is the first class called menu and other class which is connected with menu called game factions

menu:https://gist.github.com/LOLMEHA/86ff28b038d85030e346785e953644e0
gamefactions:https://gist.github.com/LOLMEHA/f05a51e07c8823a0e65cebbf81cc52ef

so this section of code that I have trouble fingering it out myself

```
import java.util.*;
public class Gamefunctions // this is a core when player choosess one of these options from the menu 
{
     String[] player =new String[2];
    double scorea = 0; // verribles of all the objects 
    double scoreb = 0;
    int i;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   double answer = 0;
    double numA, numB;
    char operator;
    char operator2;
    boolean quit = false;
    double sum1;
    double sum2;



    public void enterDetails(){ // if player select    enter details 
    for ( i=0;i<2;i++) {// tell's player to input he/she's name and stores them 
      int c=i;
      System.out.println("Welcome to the maths quiz game please input player name "+c++);
      player[i] = input.next();

    }
}

    public void mathGame(){ // if player select    enter details 

      System.out.println("Please enter your equation please "+player[0]+" press enter for each number and mathematical symbol"); // tells the player 1 to input
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("such as for ex input a number or how many you like, then hit enter and input such as /*-+^ hit enter, then  input any  number one or how many you like ");
      String s=input.next();
      numA = Double.parseDouble(s); // numa and numb and operator is the aera of player to input he/she equation 
      operator = input.next().charAt(0);
      numB = input.nextDouble();
       if () { 

       if (operator == '+') {// this is if operator is one of these like +-*/^ and then it works out the sum 
        answer = numA + numB;
        }
       if (operator == '-') {
        answer = numA - numB;
        }
       if (operator == '*') {
        answer = numA * numB;
        }
       if (operator == '/') {
        answer = numA / numB;
        }
       if (operator == '^') {
        answer = Math.pow(numA, numB);
        }
      } else {
       System.out.println("error input like for an example  '10' enter '+' enter '10'");
      }
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println(player[1]+"\t solve the equation"); // tells other player to slove the equation 
      sum2 = input.nextDouble();
      if (sum2 == answer){// checks if the answer from the player is good or not if its good he/she gets 10 points if he/she gets it wrong gets no points and shows the right answer so the player learns from his/she mistakes
        scoreb = scoreb + 10.00;
        System.out.println("correct you got 10 points to your score");
        System.out.println("");
      } else{
        System.out.println("incorrect   you got no points the correct   answer was:"+"" + answer);
      }
```

you know when the program ask to player to input his math eqtion and outputs this and continues with the program and waiting for the user to input

```
public void mathGame(){ // if player select    enter details 



    System.out.println("Please enter your equation please "+player[0]+" press enter for each number and mathematical symbol"); // tells the player 1 to input
          System.out.println("");
          System.out.println("such as for ex input a number or how many you like, then hit enter and input such as /*-+^ hit enter, then  input any  number one or how many you like ");
          String s=input.next();
          numA = Double.parseDouble(s); // numa and numb and operator is the aera of player to input he/she equation 
          operator = input.next().charAt(0);
          numB = input.nextDouble();
```

let's say that the player inputs like this 10+10 enter but it will not work since they are stored in numA which is an int, I want to make a error message saying that you can not input like this 10+10 you have to input like this 10 enter + enter 10  enter so it will be able to work
if the player inputs it correctly it will  continue the program

so if you have any problems with my explaintion of my plroblem pls  ask so I can edit it thank you for time :)

Comment: btw I use blueJ  the coding program that I use to execute the program and code with

Comment: [`Double.parseDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-) throws a [`NumberFormatException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) if there are invalid characters in its input

Comment: I don't know what exactly what it does or how it works  the double.parseDouble(.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s the bit of your code I’m going to be looking at:

```java
String s = input.next();
numA = Double.parseDouble(s);
operator = input.next().charAt(0);
numB = input.nextDouble();

if (/* Some condition */) {
    // Calculate answer
} else {
    System.out.println("error input like for an example  '10' enter '+' enter '10'");
}
```

First up, a couple nitpicks: Java is not C. You don’t need to declare all your variables at the beginning of your code blocks. `numA`, `numB` and `operator` are never used outside this bit of code, so it makes sense to declare them in here as well.

You’re also using `input.next()` with `Double.parseDouble()` once, then `input.nextDouble()` the next time. Stick to one or the other, it’ll make debugging easier if something doesn’t work properly.

And finally, what happens if someone enters `10 +1 0`? The error is silently ignored because the `1` gets picked up as part of the `operator` string then discarded by `charAt(0)`. A more resilient parsing method here would be to fetch the entire `String` first, then check for `length == 1` before calling `charAt(0)`.

```java
double numA = input.nextDouble();

String operatorString = input.next();
char operator;
if (operatorString.length() == 1) {
    operator = operatorString.charAt(0);
} else {
    // Handle error
}

double numB = input.nextDouble();

if (/* Some condition */) {
    // Calculate answer
} else {
    System.out.println("error input like for an example  '10' enter '+' enter '10'");
}
```

Onto your question then: how do we detect an invalid input? Take a look at the documentation for [`Scanner#nextDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble--) (emphasis mine):

> `public double nextDouble()`
>
> Scans the next token of the input as a double. **This method will throw `InputMismatchException` if the next token cannot be translated into a valid double value.** If the translation is successful, the scanner advances past the input that matched.

So we know `nextDouble()` can detect the invalid input for us. It does this in the form of an exception, which we can listen for (or *catch*) using a `try ... catch` statement:

```java
try {
    double numA = input.nextDouble();
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.err.printf("Invalid input! Expected number, found '%s'.\n", input.next());
}
```

We *could* extend this and wrap the entire section of code in a single `try ... catch`, but then the user would have to start again if they make one mistake. A more user-friendly solution would be this:

```java
double numA;

while (1) {
    try {
        numA = input.nextDouble();
        break;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.err.printf("Invalid input, try again! Expected number, found '%s'.\n", input.next());
    }
}
```

Note the even if you don’t print it, the call to `input.next()` is necessary to prevent an infinite loop.

Now we just need to do something similar for `operator`:

```java
char operator;

while (1) {
    String operatorString;

    try {
        operatorString = input.next();

        if (operatorString.length() != 1) {
            throw new InputMismatchException();
        }

        operator = operatorString.charAt(0);
        break;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.err.printf("Invalid input, try again! Expected character, found '%s'.\n", operatorString);
    }
}
```

This seems very similar to the previous snippet for a number - let’s try to refactor some of the common code here into a method:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ScannerGetter<T> {
    T apply() throws InputMismatchException;
}

public <T> T getValueFromScanner(ScannerGetter<T> getter, String type) {
    while(1) {
        try {
            return getter.apply();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.err.printf("Invalid input, try again! Expected %s.");
        }
    }
}
```

There’s a lot going on in these few lines. The first part declares a *functional interface* - this is a basically a custom type of lambda function. We’ll come back to that in a moment.

The method itself (`getValueFromScanner()`) is a *generic method*. It allows us to use the same method with different types in place of the *generic parameter* (`T`) without duplicating it.

This is how you’d use the above method to retrieve your three inputs:

```java
double numA = this.<Double>getValueFromScanner(() -> input.nextDouble(), "number");

char operator = this.<Char>getValueFromScanner(() -> {
    operatorString = input.next();

    if (operatorString.length() != 1) {
        throw new InputMismatchException();
    }

    return operatorString.charAt(0);
}, "operator");

double numB = this.<Double>getValueFromScanner(() -> input.nextDouble(), "number");

// Once your code gets here, all three variables will have valid values.
```